# Converting a Unicode code point into a Unicode character in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I'll start by admitting that something very basic is going over my head here.

The input (from STDIN) to my Perl code is Ç (capital c with cedilla). 
I decode it by putting this line at the top of my code :

```
binmode STDIN, ":encoding(UTF-8)";
```

Once the user inputs 'Ç', I just print it. The output is \xC7. I understand perfectly that this is so because the Unicode code point for capital c with cedilla is U+00c7.

What should I do to get the printed output on STDOUT as 'Ç', i.e., convert the code point into the character?

I have also added this line to encode the output to STDOUT :

```
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same to STDOUT as you did to STDIN:

```
perl -e 'binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";print chr(0xc7);'
```

prints

```
Ç
```

as required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @psmears. I did add this line to encode characters going to STDOUT, at the top of the code. However, a `print $str;` prints \xC7, while `print chr(0xc7);` prints "Ã‡". Please help?

Comment: @AnupamaG: `UTF-8` is not the same as `utf8`.

Comment: @AnupamaG: Are you sure your terminal is in UTF8 mode? And what happens if you run `yourprogram | xxd -` ?

Comment: @simbabque: You're right, excuse my carelessness while typing here. However, I have used `UTF-8` in the code.

Comment: @psmears: Yes, I'm using Eclipse with encoding set to UTF-8.

Comment: @AnupamaG: Are you 100% sure of that? Because "Ã‡" is *exactly* what you get if your program is outputting "Ç" encoded as UTF-8, but your terminal is interpreting it as Windows-1252 (a superset of  ISO-8859-1) instead. And what does the `xxd` command give?

Comment: @psmears: I _have_ set the "Set encoding" option in Eclipse to UTF-8 (from the default, which, as you say, was set to CP1252 as I'm using a Windows system with English as the default language). 

Again, I'm on a Windows system - so  cannot run the `xxd` command you suggested.

Comment: @AnupamaG: You could try installing `xxd` via Cygwin - it's a very useful utility for debugging encoding problems, because it lets you see exactly what bytes are coming out. How certain are you that that is the right setting in Eclipse? For example, it might now be saving your files in UTF-8, but still interpreting the terminal output as Windows-1252...

Comment: Thanks, @psmears. I will definitely do that. But any suggestions for an immediate solution would be greatly appreciated ;) 
Also, now that you say it, I'm not very sure if anything apart from the 'Set encoding' option is to be changed. Right now, I have no way of knowing how the output in the terminal is being interpreted.

Comment: From the Help section, it seems as though the 'Set encoding' option indeed changes only the encoding for the file, and not the terminal output. Now I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: @AnupamaG: Does [this page](https://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/) help?

Comment: @psmears: It certainly does, thanks a ton! `print chr(0x07)` now does print Ç. 
Thank you!